# how to convert the following syntax into an es6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, express

I have this statement to modularize my **express.js** api's:

```
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/api/users"));
```

How to write it using import statement?

inside `"./routes/api/users"`, I am exporting `express.Router()`

Comment: Have you tried anything that didn't work…?

Comment: https://medium.com/geekculture/import-export-javascript-9693b663d4f4

Comment: Thanks for the help evryone. I had to place app.use() above the app.get(*,()=>{}).

Answer (score 1):

Inside users.js use `const router = express.Router()` and then `export default router`
At the top of your file write `import router from "./routes/api/users"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use default export of es6 in "./routes/api/users" as well although it's not compulsory.

**./routes/api/users**

```
import { Router } from "express";

const router = Router();

router.get("/", (req, res)=> {
    // 
});

export default router;
```

And then import it using the following syntax.

```
import UserRoutes from "./routes/api/users";
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using node JS. So, basically nodeJS uses CommonJS by default, so you are using require() statement which is a part of CommonJS. To use the latest ES6 import export feature, go to package.json and add the following inside of the JSON container:

```
    "type": "module",
```

Note that this must be in the first object, not nested inside of anything. You can write it below the version ( for ease of understanding ).

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah. This answer is helpful as well if you're not using babel to transpile the code. If that is the case, do as suggested in the answer or read more on how to setup express app with babel [here](https://medium.com/@agavitalis/setting-up-a-nodejs-express-application-with-babel-642fe0dd45a5).